# Summation from a real number to a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

What would the solution of this be:

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^i n$

where $i$ is the imaginary unit. or any other formula really, I'm just interested to know how would a summation work from a real number to a complex number

Comment: The expression you written is not possible to definite in any consistent way. Look up how contour integration in the complex plane works

Comment: Correction: it is possible to define in some way, for example have the index run like this: $n=1,i,1+i, 2,2i,2+i, 2+2i,3,3i,3+i, ...$ however there is no way to find "the best" definition, because it's arbitrary

Comment: Basically, like in the contour integration, we have to define a "path" for the index (or the variable) to run so it gets from the starting point to the end point. There's an infinite number of paths. Contour integration works because for some functions the result is not dependent on the path

Answer (score 4):

There is no standard definition for the expression
$$
\sum_{n=1}^i n,
$$
where $i$ is the square root of $-1$. You could choose to give it your own definition, but if you are going to do so then be sure to clearly mention what your definition of this summation is.

If you happened to encounter such a summation in some context without additional information, my best guess would be that $i$ is in fact *not* the square root of $-1$, and instead just some positive integer, so that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^i n = 1 + 2 + 3 + \dots + i,
$$
where $i$ is some positive integer.